# trouble defining php script

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml

I have a problem with defining php script for my databases and two tables, RecipeDB and IngredientDB my php script seems not to display content of db. I try connect two tables with RecipeID which is primary key. But for some reason doesn't work when I write query for  simple table it works but not with two tables please help me thanks in advance

```
$conn = mysql_connect("...") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("a7956343_FoodP", $conn);

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `RecipeDB`, `IngredientDB` WHERE      
`RecipeDB.RecipeID`=`IngredientDB.RecipeID`';

$xml = new XmlWriterer();
$xml->push('recipes');

if ($result = mysql_query($sql))
{
while($Recipe = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $xml->push('Recipe');
            $xml->element('RecipeID', $RecipeDB[0]);
    $xml->element('Name', $RecipeDB[1]);
    $xml->element('Category', $RecipeDB[2]);
            $xml->element('Origin', $RecipeDB[3]);
    $xml->element('Recipe', $RecipeDB[4]);
    $xml->element('Image', $RecipeDB[5]);
            $xml->element('Favorite', $RecipeDB[6]);
            $xml->element('Image', $RecipeDB[7]);
          $xml->element('Ingredient', $IngredientDB[8]);
           $xml->element('Quantity', $IngredientDB[9]);
            $xml->pop();
}

}
```

Comment: what happens when you run the query manually in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Also I don't think XmlWriterer's exist :)

Comment: `XmlWriterer`? `XmlWriter`, surely... and you need to learn about [JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))s

Comment: Query run in phpmyadmin give me All records from both tables which is what I want

Comment: I changed to XmlWriter now when I run php script it comes up  with error

Fatal error: Call to undefined method XMLWriter::push() in /home/a7956343/public_html/dish.php on line 17

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.xmlwriter.php does not list a method named 'push'

Comment: I did include 
include('XmlWriter.class.php');

and as I said it works with one table problem is with connceting to that second table but not sure where

Answer (score 0):

All you need's change the class name of  '`XmlWriterer()`' in it's file.php! Hope that'll help!